# UISwipeGestureRecognizer fails in ios13 without fullscreen modalpresentationstyle

Tags: swift, ios13

I'm adapting my app to ios13. `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` for moving left and right between pages in part of my app worked well in ios12, but now the functions aren't called when the default card presentation modal transition is used. If I force the viewcontroller to be fullscreen it works as before, but I'd rather use the default modal transition option.

I tried overriding `gestureRecognizer(:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith)` (which wasn't called, and didn't work). `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` worked normally, as did `UIPanGestureRecognizer`. I added my swipeGestureRecognizer in storyboards, and tested with pinchGestureRecognizer in the same way.

Comment: Have the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set a delegate on your gesture recognizer and add the method

```
gestureRecognizer(_:,shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith:)
```

to your delegate and return true this appears to fix the issue

Comment: Thanks user2898617; setting the delegate on the gesture recognizer was the key step I missed